# Can "響く" have the meaning of "to come (home); to remain (with someone)"?

Tags: meaning, words

I looked up 響{ひび}く on jisho.org, where I found the meaning "to come (home); to remain (with someone)" under definition 3. I was curious and checked a few monolingual online dictionaries, but none of them seemed to have an entry with the same or a similar meaning.

Is the meaning under definition 3 on jisho.org not really used or not literal enough for monolingual dictionaries? Or did I just overlook it when searching through them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A very tricky question, but it is a good one mainly because it made me think.

「響{ひび}く」 ***can*** indeed mean "to come home" and "to remain with someone".  Only five minutes ago, however, I was going to say the completely opposite thing.  Here is why:

In this case, "to come home" should mean "**to become very clear in an unpleasant way**" and not "to come back to one's residence".  「（心に）響く」 does have that meaning.

Likewise, 「響く」 can also mean "**(of kind words, etc.) to remain (or to be effective) with a person**".　「[Person] に響く」 means exactly that.

Jisho is like that, but people love it.

Comment: Hmm... that usage of "to come home" sounds strange to me. I think the normal phrase would be "to *hit* home", would it not? And I don't think it necessarily has to be unpleasant (neither does 心に響く、I think)